# Javascript firing event more than once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal which gets its content via another php script. The contents then load with the user's selected ID and enable them to edit the contents.

The modal itself is loaded just above this within a separate dynamic container.

The issue is this:

> Click modal for the first time: 1 event fired.
>
> Second time: modal event fires 2 times.
>
> Third time: event fires 3 times
>
> and so on...

I've tried unique IDs and event unbinding with no luck - any ideas?
I've read a few questions already but haven't come across a solution that works for me.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.modal-launcher'+rates_randid+'').unbind('click').click(function(e){
    //modal and modal body selection
    var modal = $('#modal_launcher'+modalid+''), modalBody = $('.modal-loader-content'+modalid+'');
    //Gets ID for the rate that needs editing.
    rateid = $(this).data('rateid');
    //on show of modal send ID and grab page/contents
    modal.on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            $.post('pages/edit_rate_modal.php?rateid='+rateid+'',{func:'edit'})
        .done(function(data){
            $('.modal-loader-content'+modalid+'').html(data);
        })
        })
    //show modal
        .modal();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#modal_launcher').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('.modal-loader-content').empty();
})
</script>
```

Comment: On each click, you are binding a new `show.bs.modal` event. So don't nest events or at least try: `modal.one('show.bs.modal', function () {... });`

Comment: Ah!! thank you!! thats brilliant! 
Yeah I will be re-writing this part when I get to adding the next page's modal windows. Just havent decided how I want it to share it yet.
Thanks very much though!

Comment: Could you pop that onto an answer, so I can accept that as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind modal show event only once:

```
modal.one('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $.post('pages/edit_rate_modal.php?rateid=' + rateid, {
        func: 'edit'
    })
        .done(function (data) {
        $('.modal-loader-content' + modalid).html(data);
    })
})
//show modal
.modal();
```

But your best bet would be to not nest this event inside click handler.